# How to make start:interval:end column in excel?

Tags: excel

In excel I'd like to be able to fill a column with linearly spaced values without having to drag the formula down.

For example, I want to be able to:

- start at `0`
- move in steps of `0.1`
- fill the next cell
- stop before going over `2*pi`

I would imagine something like this would work:

```
0:0.1:2*pi()
```

Is it possible to do this with excel? In the past I would fill the top cell with `0` then make a formula that increases by `0.1` and drag it down and mess around with it until the last value is where I'd like it to be. I don't like this method and would like a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the **Home** tab on the Ribbon, pull-down:

**Fill > Series...**

Then specify your needs in the Dialog box.